# Looking for an extension to calculate price based on product configuration

Tags: extensions

Firstly this is not for a webshop, but it is for a page for our product.

The requirement for the joomla extension is that calculates a price based on how many users, customers our client wants and which add-ons the client wants.

So our client should see a calculation like this:

3 users $x pr. month

n additional users n times $y pr. month

m each additional 100 customers m times $z pr. month

This gives a total pr. month

Then there are setup (once only) fees

Credit card payment setup $y

And then at the bottom a total for the first year(!) which includes the once only fees and a total for following years (without the once only fees).

Comment: What's the actual question you're asking?

Comment: I doubt you'll find an extension for such a specific case, but if you know some JavaScript, I think that's the way to go. [This tutorial](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml) walks you through a similar problem, and [this commercial plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-price-calculator/8242357) might be another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find an extension that fits your exact requirements, you will need to get hold of a reputable developer and build something specific to your needs. They don't need to be a Joomla Developer as your needs can all be accomplished with javascript.

This should not be too difficult to set up as there is nothing to save and nothing else (from what you say) to do with this data once calculated.

maybe 10 lines of Javascript (or jQuery lib) ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping a bit for someone knowing an extension that only needed minor adaption. Guess I'll just have to code it myself.